# "$@" in shell separates arguments with quotes even though it shouldn't

Tags: python, shell, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments

I'm trying to parse arguments in a shell script for a python program. We're using a wrapper who takes the command line arguments and calls the correct python module. 
For some reason, it keeps splitting up args I'm passing with double quotes. This is how I get the args:

```
args="$@"
```

Then I run:

```
runner.sh --host="XHOST 1"
```

or

```
runner.sh --host "XHOST 1"
```

the "$@" breaks the "XHOST 1" into 2 separate tokens of XHOST and 1.
First I've tried using the "$*" as always, but it didn't work. Now I'm using $@ and it keeps splitting the args. This was tested on a rhel-7.2 machine.

Is there another way to parse shell args to try and keep them as one token when they are wrapped in quotes? Am I missing something here?

Comment: `args="$@"` is inherently broken, inasmuch as it's trying to stuff an array into a string -- inherently a less capable datatype. `args=( "$@" )` stores your array *as an array*, so the data is all still there. (Needs to be expanded as `"${args[@]}"`, but that's not exactly problematic).

Comment: ...which is to say: the array expansion `"$@"` is fine, but `$args` (expanding a string variable you populated from that array expansion) is not. See also [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Comment: Thanks! this helped a lot :)